# Получение HWND диспетчера задач на C

Tags: c, winapi

Нужно получить handle окна диспетчера задач. У меня есть программа, которая по истечении определенного времени открывает на весь экран окно и не даёт его закрыть. Ну, понятно, я просто не обрабатываю `WM_CLOSE`. Но хотелось бы, чтобы программа блокировала и закрытие с помощью диспетчера задач. Я осуществлял это постоянным перемещением мышки в одно и то же место, но это как-то не круто... Поэтому я хотел убить само окно диспетчера при нажатии Ctrl+Alt+Delete

Comment: Уточните, зачем вам это нужно, и читали ли вы про Киокс-Мод в Windows и похожие штатные способы полноэкранных неубиваемых приложений?

Comment: похоже на попытку написать классический вымогатель